# A question about the four-color problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

I remember there was a theorem in the history, concerning the four-color problem. It states something like following: *in a map, the maximal number of regions that can be neighbors to each other is 4*. However, this didn't prove the four-color theorem for some reason. What is the name of the theorem? I am trying to find the exact statement and the proof of this theorem, to understand why it didn't prove the four-color problem.

Comment: $4$ is maximal. So $K_5$ cannot be done ... In other words, $K_5$ does not have a planar embedding ... That's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem

Comment: I think the most obvious reason it doesn't prove the four color theorem is that there is no maximum number of regions that can be adjacent to another on a map. For example China borders 14 other countries.

Comment: A fairly recent Question, [Why is this proof for the four color theorem considered wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379470/why-is-this-proof-for-the-four-color-theorem-considered-wrong), explores some related ideas and might be of interest to you.  Also note that a map with regions each having only two neighbors can nonetheless require three colors, so the maximum *degree* of a map is not an upper bound on the chromatic number (colors required) of a map.

Answer (score 2):

[Four-color theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-ColorTheorem.html#:%7E:text=The%20four%2Dcolor%20theorem%20states,conjectured%20the%20theorem%20in%201852.) states that any map in a plane can be colored using four colors in such a way that regions sharing a common boundary (other than a single point) do not share the same color. It also supposes that there are no exclaves. So in graph theory formulation, considering countries as vertices and common non-degenerate borders as edges, theorem states that each planar graph is 4-colorable.

You say that each planar graph doesn't have a subgraph isomorphic to $K_5$, and this is correct. But [clique number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliqueNumber.html) gives only lower bound on [chromatic number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html). You may consider the cycle $C_5$. It is $K_3$-free, but it is not $2$-colorable. Also there are $K_3$-free graphs with arbitrary high chromatic number.